# Why does java ignore the first part of the print statement when concatenated with a boolean statement?

Tags: java, system.out, java-print

Suppose I  have this code

```
public class Test{
    public static void main (String args[]) { 
        String s = "thrones";
        System.out.println("Game of" + "thrones" == s) ;
    }
}
```

The output of the above code block is just 
'false'

But shouldn't it print 
'Game of true'

However if i put a parenthesis for the ("thrones"==s), it prints properly

```
System.out.println("Game of" +    ("thrones"==s));
```

'Game of true'

I am just curious why it isn't taking the first part of the print in the first case. I just want to know whats going on there while compiling.

Thanks.

Comment: Would `1+       1==2` be true? (or would it give you an error saying you can't add an int and a boolean?) Spaces are ignored.

Comment: Shouldn't it print "false"?

Comment: At least 2 potential issues: 1. You don't use `==` to compare strings in Java. 2. You obviously know you operator precedence better than me - I'd add some `()` to make it clear what your intent is...

Comment: You have got the "precedence" part of the answer here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html (+ is interpreted before ==)

Answer (score 1):

[First, it really prints `false`](http://ideone.com/TJBiDP), because `"Game of thrones" != "thrones"`!

Second, you seem to have answered your own question. It's parsing `"Game of" + "thrones" == s` as `("Game of" + "thrones") == s`, because [the `+` operator has a higher precedence than the `==` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: oh ..yes!! I didn't realize that! . Its first concatenating and then comparing. got it. Thanks

Comment: Also, you should really use the `String.equals()` method to compare strings.

Comment: why so? isn't it the same?

Comment: @shashank check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for the difference between `==` and `String.equals()`.